# Is it possible to ZIP a folder in FTP using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, download, ftp, zip

How to zip a folder existing on an FTP server using C# code? Is there any alternate method to download files fast from FTP?

I were using the below code to zip and download files from server.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
    zip.AddDirectoryByName("Preview_" + id);

    foreach (var item in lstpp)
    {
        foreach (var itm in item.ImageList)
        {
            string filePath = itm.pPath;
            zip.AddFile(filePath, "Preview_" + id);
        }
    }
    response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    string zipName =
        String.Format("Preview_" + id + ".zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.End();
}
```

But it can not be reused for the FTP download.

Comment: I assume this is client-side code (run on the side that receives the files)? You can only work on the file directly on the server. So unless FTP has a stream-compression feature, there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

There's no API in the FTP protocol to ZIP files on the server.

---

It's not uncommon that one, in addition to an FTP access, have also an SSH access. If that's the case, you can connect with the SSH and execute the `zip` shell command on the server to compress the files. Then you can download the ZIP file using the FTP protocol (Though if you have the SSH access, you will also have an SFTP access. Then, use the SFTP instead of the FTP.).

---

Some (very few) FTP servers offer an API to execute an arbitrary shell (or other) commands using the `SITE EXEC` command (or similar). But that's really very rare. You can use this API the same way as the SSH above.